# How to solve Kruppa's Equations for self calibration for images

Tags: matlab, opencv, 3d, 3d-reconstruction

I have a set of uncalibrated images (4 or 5 images).
In each of those images, I have detected 60 feature points and have matched them in each image.
It can be assured that this is accurate upto a very good scale.

Now ,
a need a method to calibrate camera(same or varying intrinsic parameters).
Kruppa's equations are recommended but the method to solve them are very intense and i cannot find any implementations online.

Can someone suggest a method for doing so , and also solving for dual image of absolute quadric?

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show effort solving the problem with a way clearer statement. What are Kruppa's equations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_reconstruction_from_multiple_images
Please see Kruppa's equation in this.
Also,https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9493/0b7aefcaa413c0fcc8dd7a061769f950f018.pdf